# Multiple select DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have:

```
if (count($data['paymentTypes'])<5) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach (array_values($data['paymentTypes']) as $value) { $arr[]=$value->getId(); }
    $query = $query->leftJoin('p.payments','g')->where('g.id IN(:num)')->setParameter('num', $arr);
}

if (count($data['expertise']->toArray())>0) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach (array_values($data['expertise']->toArray()) as $value) { $arr[]=$value->getId(); }
    $query = $query->leftJoin('p.expertise','g')->where('g.id IN(:num)')->setParameter('num', $arr);
}
```

How may I stop the query from breaking in case both statements are true? I would expect leftjoins and wheres to congregate but they throw an exception instead. What is the cleanest way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You should try to use different alias and parameter name in the second part than in the first.

Comment: Duh! Thank you thank you thank you! Always nice to have an extra pair of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Use different alias and parameter name in the second part than in the first.